# Getting the real Useragent String from a Proxy-based Browser

Tags: javascript, user-agent, nokia, nokia-s40

I noticed something that seems a little odd when using a Nokia Asha 311.

When I use `navigator.userAgent` from the device's DOM, I get something very similar to the following:

```
mozilla/5.0 (x11; linux86_64; rv:5.0.1) gecko/20121205 osre/2.2.1.4
```

However, if I go to http://whatismyuseragent.com or http://show-ip.net/useragent/ to check, I get this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Series40; Nokia305/gadCEX3.60; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1) Gecko/20100401 S400viBrowser/2.0.2.68.9
```

I'm assuming that these Web sites are getting the user agent from the HTTP Request Headers, and that the Nokia Asha is using a proxy-based browser (Nokia Xpress Browser) which is causing the user agent to be altered?!

Is it possible to get the real user agent string?! I'm keen on something 100% client-side as I need this for some functionality in a JQuery Plugin.

Thanks.